# Why is there a cast to (char *) before pointer arithmetic? (container_of() internals)

Tags: c, pointers, casting, linux-kernel, macros

The macro is defined by

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

I've looked around at some other questions on here and some other resources on the internet and I'm pretty sure I understand how this macro works.

What I think it does:
In the first line it creates a new pointer with the type of a pointer to the type of member and assigns that pointer the value of the given pointer. Then in the second line it uses offsetof to find the address of the beginning of the struct or union.

My question is why is this line `const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);` here. It seems like the proper pointer type is set and then immediately cast to a `char *` in the next line.

So the question I have is why does `__mptr` have to be cast to a different type of pointer at all? Why can't it be left as whatever type I just set it to be and then subtract the offset from that pointer since I am casting it again after the subtraction anyway. Furthermore, while I (think) I understand what the first line is doing, I don't understand why it is even necessary.

Why is doing it in this way better than this:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
            const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
            (type *)(__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

or this

```
 #define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
             (type *)( (char *)ptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Comment: If you don't cast to `char*` the pointer arithmetic will yield a different result on any type whose size is not `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @paddy: Strictly speaking, even iff the size is the same, using a different type violates strict aliasing rules, thus invokes UB.

Comment: @Olaf, lol, but it's like speeding, right? Technically against the law, but it's downright weird if you actually drive at the posted speed.

Comment: @paddy So we cast it to a char* because a char has a size of 1 byte? Cause doesn't every pointer have the size?

Comment: It's not about the size of the pointer.  It's about the size of the type it points to.  Read up on how pointer arithmetic works in C.  Also, @Olaf has a good point about strict aliasing.  However, if you're confused about pointer arithmetic, then perhaps learn about that before tackling strict aliasing.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: In my country we have streets you can drive as fast as you can. No need for illegal speeding if it is just for driving >200km/h. Just let's hope the programmers of your car's computer systems did not think the same and followed the standard ...

Comment: @Olaf pointer arithmetic doesn't violate aliasing rules

Comment: @paddy But are you using char just because on a normal system, a char is 1 byte and therefore subtracting a number of bytes won't have that multiplying effect like DigitalRoss pointed out below? Or is there another reason you use char?

Comment: I don't see any reason why `__mptr` is necessary, perhaps it is just for debugging or something

Comment: @M.M: Not as such, but acessing lateron does. But I agree the cast is mostly for the size. Anyway, that macro actually leads to invoking UB when the pointers are used afterwards, because dereferencing a pointer outside its array is UB, too. (Just relax, I use that macro myself - It's just one has to know when bending the rules and when not - except for speeding:-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because subtraction would otherwise incorrectly multiply the offset by the size of ptr.

That is, without it, you would get the following result:

```
(type *)( (char *)__mptr - sizeof *__mptr * offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Comment: Ahh okay, what about why you can't just use `ptr` and cast that to a char*?

Comment: One could, so it's hard to say why  `__mptr` was stirred in. It may eliminate a warning when the parameter type is something odd, or it may interact with the optimizer and the alias-detection-based optimization that was being discussed above. Maybe it worked around a bug.